# Loading .NET 4.5.2 assembly in .NET 4 application, reflection & reference

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

It is allowed to load the .NET 4.5.2 assembly (using reflection) in the application whose exe is compiled using .NET 4 framework. However if I reference the same assembly in that application during development (added as any other assembly reference), build fails.

Why is it the case that thing which is not allowed during development is allowed at runtime using reflection?

Comment: May I know why this question is downvoted? What's wrong in this question?

Comment: Only because something is possible deosn´t mean it´s a good idea to do so. However when you load an assembly at runtime, how can you even check what you´re doing might or might not be allowed? You can´t. This is why it´s *allowed*, however not good as it might fail *at runtime*.

Comment: @HimBromBeere : Why is it a bad idea to load using reflection if for some reason I cannot compile my main application on newer .NET version? And more important in this question for me is to understand why it's allowed if it's not something we are supposed to do?

Comment: The problem is: there´s no way for the compiler to check if the assembly you´re dynamically loading *at runtime* is in the correct format.

Comment: .NET 4.5 is an in-place upgrade of .NET 4. As far as the runtime is concerned, it's still .NET 4, so it will happily load .NET 4.5 assemblies. They would even work if they didn't reference anything from .NET 4.5. But Visual Studio helpfully points out that this is almost certainly not what you want, since you could just be targeting .NET 4 in that case.

Comment: @JeroenMostert : Thanks. Will .4.5 specific method call fail just because application is .NET 4? Or will it succeed if .NEt 4 app is running on machine having .NET 4.5.2 installed?

Comment: @Learner, if you attempt to invoke a method, by Reflection, that doesn't exist you'll get a `MissingMethodException` thrown. I *think* you'll get a similar result if you manage to persuade your app to call a v4.5 method when only v4.0 is installed by some form of shenanigans, but ordinarily I think you'd get a message pop up on application startup which is something I can't readily reproduce

Comment: Unfortunately, it depends. If the app references assemblies using version 4, it may get different ones than if it does so asking for version 4.5. This means that your assembly, which is loaded in the context of the process, may also be confronted with a version 4 assembly. This depends on how versioning is done, and I don't know how the situation is for all the framework assemblies. It would, in general, be extremely unwise to count on this working.

Comment: @Learner the earliest supported .NET version is 4.5.2. *Why* are you trying to mix versions? Just upgrade to 4.0. 4.5.2 is a replacement for 4.0 anyway, which means that if there are 4.5.2 assemblies to load, you are *already* running on 4.5.2

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I dare not say this is true for all BCL assemblies (it might be, but I don't know), and even if it is, to programmers it's not clear cut when something is a BCL assembly and when it's something provided by Microsoft that may or may not count as BCL. I'd adopt a "better safe than sorry" policy on this and load 4.5 assemblies only after I established that I'm running on 4.5, and use runtime reflection of individual types/methods for every other scenario. That is, in the past; these days I don't care about supporting .NET 4 anymore. :-P

Comment: @JeroenMostert 4.5.2 is the earliest supported version. Other applications or Windows Update itself may have already upgraded any previous versions to 4.5.2 or higher.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: pay me enough money and I'll work with any old thing you care to name, supported or not. :-) There used to be a time when .NET 4 was still supported and these scenarios were more relevant than they are now.

Comment: @JeroenMostert 4 is used only in Windows XP. You missed the point - the *target* will have a newer version simply because it got updated by Windows Update. As for money - you can't use TLS1.2 in 4.0. Service providers have already retired anything less than TLS1.1 and many require TLS1.2. That's one reason why people try to mix 4.0 and 4.5.2 - they installed 4.5.2 to get TLS1.2 through the binaries and a hack, but don't want to upgrade their projects.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I suspect we're talking past each other in terms of scenarios. The discussion isn't improving the question, though, so I'll just leave it at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading an assembly, or doing anything really, via Reflection is a "*here there be dragons*" scenario where you're assuming the risk, and reacting to, anything that goes wrong (such as an assembly that targets a later version of the framework than is available).

I only see Compiler warnings when referencing a project that targets a higher framework version:

> The referenced project 'ProjectForNetFramework45' is targeting a higher framework version (4.6.1) than this project’s current target framework version (4.0). This may lead to build failures if types from assemblies outside this project’s target framework are used by any project in the dependency chain.

Rather than a build failure, until I actually attempt to call a method in the v4.5 assembly at which point the following pops up:

> error CS0400: The type or namespace name 'ProjectForNetFramework45' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)

The 4.5 version of the .net Framework is an "in-place update" rather than a new version, see the [notes in this Microsoft blog post about Compatibility of .NET Framework 4.5](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2011/09/26/compatibility-of-net-framework-4-5/):

> .NET Framework 4.5 is an in-place update that replaces .NET Framework 4 (rather than a side-by-side installation). Our goal is for .NET 4.5 to be fully backward compatible with applications built for .NET 4 (.NET 3.5 and .NET 4.5 will be side-by-side). We’ll talk about the compatibility story for .NET 3.5 in a later post. One of the first things you’ll notice about .NET 4.5 is the version number (4.0.30319) is the same as .NET 4; this is the practice used by other in-place updates.

This means that, rather than being a different version of the runtime (i.e. the JIT, Garabage Collector, etc,.. although these do change!), a newer framework will likely add new classes, interfaces and methods to existing classes giving a wider API to work against. This is one of the things that "[netstandard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard)" is an attempt to add clarity to.